# Django 1.5 mongodb does not wotk

Tags: django, mongodb, installation, django-nonrel, django-1.5

I'm  working in two projects, the first one is been developed using django/mysql and the other uses django/mongodb.

The first is using django1.5 and it works but the second only works in django1.3, I believe mongodb does not work in django1.5.

When I try to run the django/mongodb project in django1.5 I get:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

How can I solve it? can I install both django(1.3 and 1.5) in the same computer and use them for some different projects?

I'm a newbie with mongodb.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well that's right a Tuple is immutable ,so you can't insert it nothing after declared.

Comment: so, what could be my mistake? the same settings.py works with mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I installed both django1.5 to use mysql and 1.3 to use mongodb.

I got it using virtualenv

Here a bit tutorial(In spainsh)
http://plone-spanish-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/python/creacion_entornos_virtuales.html